# How to reduce the size of the windows icons in the xfce4-panel taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, icons, xfce

How can I reduce the size of the windows icons in the xfce4-panel taskbar?

I've reduced the height of my xfce4-panel from 20px to 16px and now the icons in the taskbar are truncated by one or two pixels at the top and the bottom instead of having a smaller size.

I've tried some changes in my `.gtkrc-2.0` file but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do do this?

Comment: By which I assume you mean adding the line gtk-icon-sizes = "gtk-menu=22,16" or similar?  Which version of XFCE and/or what distribution are you running?

Comment: Yup that's the kind of things I tried. It's xfce4-panel 4.6.4-1 from Debian testing.

Comment: Ahh--that explains it.  Posting answer now.

Answer (score 2):

In xfce4-panel 4.6 this setting can be changed from the terminal with the command

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p '/Gtk/IconSizes' -s 'gtk-menu=16,16'
```

Or, from the Settings Editor you can go to `xsettings` -> `Gtk`, then select `IconSizes`, click on the `Edit property` icon and enter `gtk-menu=16,16` or other desired size in `Value :`.

Just as a heads up and for future reference, this changes again for xfce-panel 4.8 where different panels and menus are adjusted separately; so you will need to set `/Gtk/IconSizes` to something like `panel-applications-menu=16,16:gtk-menu=16,16:panel-directory-menu=16,16` depending on your needs.

From [here](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=4676) and [here](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5726).

Comment: Thanks for your time! So I had to create the property with `xfconf-query -c xsettings -n -p '/Gtk/IconSizes' -t string -s 'gtk-menu=12,12'` but it doesn't seem to have any effet, even if I kill xfce4-panel and spawn it again. I also tried what you suggested for v4.8 but it didn't have any effect either.

Comment: @p4bl0 You will actually have to restart xfce as a whole to see the change, I believe.  There may also be a minimum size for the icons, though I don't know what it is.  One way to check this would be to set the numbers very large and then progressively lower them.

Comment: I don't have xfce installed, only its panel. I tried to set a bigger size and to relaunch it again, it had no effect :-/. It seems what I want is impossible... Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: @p4bl0 you might have to restart GNOME or your window manager whatever it is--and/or the whole computer.  It seems unlikely to me that this value doesn't exist _anywhere_.

Comment: I restarted Openbox (my window manager, I don't have any desktop environment) and even logout/login but it didn't had any effect with all the value I tried (12,12 which is what I want, but also 10,10 and 30,30). It seems unlikely that rebooting will be of any help but I'll try later, just in case.

Comment: Rebooting didn't work either. Maybe this feature needs some other parts of Xfce that I don't have? Too bad it's a bit ugly but it's not that much annoying...

Comment: I've paged through the documentation on xfce4-panel but I think this would probably need to be answered conclusively by someone more deeply familiar with the code and/or structure.  Sorry I couldn't help you!

Comment: @eMansipater: no problem, you clear have done more than your part of the job ;-). I can't accept your answer since it doesn't solve my problem but I wish I could upvote it one more time... :-).